# Formatting son object

Tags: json

I have a json object like this where dates are hardcoded. I want to update the value at from in same format but yesterdays date i.e 20180612 and today's date  i.e. 20180613 automatically. I don't want to hardcode the dates. Any help will be useful

```
{
    "event_name": "c_city_selected",
    "from": 20180610,
    "to": 20180611
}
```

Comment: Any code? What language You use, friend?

Comment: You need to tell us your language. What have you tried at the moment?

Comment: I am following an example from  here and I want to update the dates in query_example.jso https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-csv-download and call the commands as mentioned there